# How to apply MakeModal() method on frame with child dialog

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am using wxPython Classic on Python 27. I have my files structure as follow (see codes snippet below):-

**frame.py** = this file contains two classes for  frame and dialog (MyFrame1 and MyDialog1 respectively)

**main.py** = this file import the classes above and also contains two sub-classes based on the above (MyFrame2 and MyDialog2 respectively).

Now keeping the file structure as it is above, how do I make the Frame window inactive when the dialog window is opened?

How can the MakeModal() method be properly applied on the file arrangement/structure above? All the examples I found so far make uses of two frames instead of a frame and a dialog.

**frame.py**

```
import wx

# ************ FRAME 1 ************ #
# ************ FRAME 1 ************ #
class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.child_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Child Frame", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer.Add( self.child_button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.child_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_child_button )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def On_child_button( self, event ):
        event.Skip()



# ************ DIALOG 1 ************ #
# ************ DIALOG 1 ************ #
class MyDialog1 ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 300,200 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )


        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def onClose( self, event ):
        event.Skip()
```

---

**main.py**

```
import wx
from frame import MyFrame1, MyDialog1


class MyFrame2(MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        MyFrame1.__init__ (self, parent)

    def On_child_button( self, event ):
        MyDialog2(None).Show()


class MyDialog2(MyDialog1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        MyDialog1.__init__ (self, parent)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()


app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame2(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: try ShowModal() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `MakeModal` on the frame, as dialogs already have modality functionality built-in.  Just call the dialog's `ShowModal` method instead of the `Show` method. `ShowModal` will create a nested event loop so `ShowModal` will not return until the dialog is finished, and input to the other windows in the application will be blocked. A typical usage pattern looks like this:

```
with MyDialog(self, foo, bar) as dlg:
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        # do something with dlg values
```